# Ubuntu 16.04: where to set Xim server name?

Tags: ibus, fcitx

I am using `fcitx 4.2.9.1`. When running `fcitx-diagnose`, I get the following error regarding the `Xim` section:

### Xim:

1. `${XMODIFIERS}`:

   Environment variable XMODIFIERS is set to "@im=fcitx" correctly.
   Xim Server Name from Environment variable is fcitx.
2. XIM_SERVERS on root window:

   **Xim server name: "ibus" is different from that set in the environment variable: "fcitx".**

I have set keyboard input method system as fcitx in Language Support. I am confused why Xim server name is still ibus. Where can I modify Xim server name?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as you,I fixed it by remove the ibus .However  I found the unity desktop environment is gone after you remove ibus.

Comment: It is not a good choose to fix it

Answer (score 0):

add the following to `/etc/environment` or `~/.xprofile`

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
```